# Manually trigger Root Certificate Update on Windows

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate

Is there a way to manually trigger a Root Certificate Update?

I'm troubleshooting a problem with a certificate that keeps disappearing from the Certificate Store. I think this is related to [Trusted root certificate being automatically removed from store](https://serverfault.com/questions/639280/trusted-root-certificate-being-automatically-removed-from-store). But I want to be sure, so I need to be able to trigger the Root Certificate Update - otherwise I have to keep waiting for it to happen at some random time.

Comment: Does a gupdate /force /wait:-1 do it for you?